# PC (Intel x86) server install CD

Tags: 64-bit, intel

Does PC (Intel x86) server install CD version supports 64-bit?

It's little bit confusing - the AMD version explicitly mentioned 64-bit support.

fgeld

Comment: plz explain briefly.

Answer (score 1):

**Intel x86 server** doesn't support 64-bit applications because Intel x86 version means 32 bit version.It only supports 32 bit applications.

Comment: Yes, that is correct - x86 refers to 32-bit architecture while AMD refers to 64-bit architecture. Hence AMD software will _not_ install on a x86 machine.